# How to install packages in conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. It comes with Python 3.8. I have installed Conda and have created a conda environment. I have activated the Conda env by using

`conda activate myproject`.

I can see that now it's activated.

I open another terminal which do not have any Conda env activated. When I do `which python3`, it shows

`/usr/bin/python3.8` . I then install a package in this interpreter by using command:

`pip3 install opencv-python`. It gets installed successfully.

Inside conda env, I do `which python3`, it shows

`/home/john/anaconda3/envs/myproject/bin/python3` and when I load `cv2` (which I installed in `/usr/bin/python3`), it is imported fine without any error and in fact I have not installed OpenCV in Conda env. How is this possible? Am I missing something?

How can a package which is installed in local interpreter also showing in Conda env ? How do I make sure that there is no mix up of packages?

Comment: See duplicate. Essentially, Conda does not block user site, which is likely where you installed the `opencv`. Let me know if the duplicate marking is unclear in any way.